# Linearising two coupled bosonic modes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, bosons, coupled-oscillators, linearized-theory

In Sec. IV of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.04821) the authors consider the Hamiltonian (Eq. 10)

$$
H = \omega_a a^\dagger a + \omega_b b^\dagger b - g_0 a^\dagger a (b + b^\dagger)
$$

in the regime $\omega_a / \omega_b \approx 10^5$.

They write under Eq. 10 that $H$ can be transformed by "linearizing the system and [making] the rotating wave approximation" (after presumably transforming to the rotating frame) into the Hamiltonian

$$
H' = g_0 (a^\dagger b + a b^\dagger).
$$

It seems they cannot mean this in any precise sense, as $a^\dagger a$ is an integral of motion of $H$ and there is no such corresponding integral of motion in $H'$.

My question is *in what sense can $H$ be transformed into $H'$*? I am not seeing see how the approximations described relate the two Hamiltonians.

Edit: The only way I can see this can work at the moment is if I introduce a third mode $\omega_c \approx \omega_a \pm \omega_b$. In a linearised Hamiltonian this mode can be used to absorb the energy difference of the $a,b$ modes in a process of asymmetric parametric up/down conversion. If $\omega_c$ is strongly pumped this mode may further be treated classically and drops out of the problem as a quantum degree of freedom, potentially leaving an effective description like $H'$. This would "renormalise" $g_0$, is it reasonable to assume this is what the authors were imagining?